# Thinkpad yoga x1 gen 2 freezes completely when stylus is used ubuntu 20.04.2

Tags: drivers, kernel, thinkpad, stylus

The moment the stylus gets near the screen the entire laptop freezes and becomes unresponsive (this just randomly started happening) I tried re-installing the driver, but it has not helped (I take all my notes on this laptop), I've been searching for answers and couldn't find the exact problem. I was hoping someone here might be able to help me with the issue...

Comment: New headers are out and the bug seems to be fixed on my laptop (yoga x1 gen 4), just do `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` and reboot

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on my Lenovo Yoga C740 with kernel 5.8.0-45 on Groovy, fixed by downgrading to 5.8.0-44.

Comment: New headers are out (5.8.49) and the bug seems to be fixed on my laptop (yoga x1 gen 4), just do `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` and reboot

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved apparently it was an issue with corrupted data in the kernel for the wacom2 stylus driver, it was fixed by updating the entire kernel.

Comment: Thank you for this advice. Have you any documentation about this ? How to update the kernel to this patched version ? By the way, there is a bug report on launchpad https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libwacom/+bug/1920682

Comment: The problem was apparently not solved, at least as of 5.8.0-48.  I also had to revert to 5.8.0-44.